# Highcharts angular cannot read property 'series' of undefined

Tags: angular, highcharts

I've got this error message. I would really like to dig into highstock.js and the supporting files, but I'm not sure how to.

The chart displays fine, but it always throws this error.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide some code, it will be easier for people to help you then.

Comment: can you reproduce this in stackblitz.com?

Comment: Please reproduce your issue on the online editor. Here is a basic template which you can start from https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stock

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because when loading the page, data coming from the observer are not completely loaded and the series is still undefined.
Just add a condition to your div tag to avoid this message.
For exemple something like this in the HTML:

```
    <div *ngIf="loaded">
       <highcharts-chart 
         [Highcharts]="Highcharts" 
         [options]="chartOptionsXrangeCS"
         style="width: 100%; display: block;">
      </highcharts-chart>
    </div>
```

and a boolean named "loaded" in your component that you put at true at the end of the suscribe method.